# how to properly enable SSL on localhost

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I have a web application (java, jsp)running on tomcat 7 . It runs perfectly fine when i do `http://localhost.somedomain.com/`

i want to enable SSL so that i can access my site `https://localhost.somedomain.com/`

I have installed self signed certificate  and configured httpd.conf ( on apache) 
by following the steps as explained in

```
https://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-ssl
```

when i access `https://localhost.somedomain.com/` it seems to look for index.html to serve  . i added a dummy index.html in root of my web application and it gets served. It seems to serve as static file than rendering it as a web application(executing the controller as done by the http version ). When i access https://localhost.somedomain.com/url/   it reports a 404 /url/ not found

My first question is ,

1. do i need to do any configuration to tomcat (server.xml) in addition to changes in httpd.conf (apache)

My second question is ,

2. in httpd.conf i have given the document root as the folder where the webapplication is deployed to (/apps/sstp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT) , Is this correct? my httpd.conf entry is as below

my httpd.conf file is as below

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
Listen 80
Listen 443

    LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
    LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
    LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
    LoadModule socache_shmcb_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so
    LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
    LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
    LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
    LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
    LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
    LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
    LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
    LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
    LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
    LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
    LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    LoadModule proxy_express_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_express.so
    LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
    LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
    LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
    LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
    LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
    LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
    LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so

    <IfModule unixd_module>
        User _www
        Group _www

    </IfModule>

                ServerAdmin you@example.com

                ServerName localhost.somedomain.com


                    <Directory />
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
                </Directory>

                DocumentRoot "/apps/sstp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"
                <Directory "/apps/sstp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT">
                Require all granted
                Options Includes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
            </Directory>

            <IfModule dir_module>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
            </IfModule>

            <FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
            Require all denied
        </FilesMatch>

        <Files "rsrc">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    <DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"

        LogLevel warn

        <IfModule log_config_module>
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

            <IfModule logio_module>
                # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
                LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
            </IfModule>

            CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common

        </IfModule>

        <IfModule alias_module>

            ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"

        </IfModule>

        <IfModule cgid_module>
        </IfModule>

        <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mime_module>
        TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    </IfModule>

    TraceEnable off
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
    <IfModule proxy_html_module>
        Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf
    </IfModule>

    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>
    Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf is as below

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin a@b.com
            DocumentRoot "/apps/sstp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"
            ServerName localhost.somedomain.com
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.crt"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.key"
     </VirtualHost>
```

my httpd-ssl.conf is as below

```
        Listen 443
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
    SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
    SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
    SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
    SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/private/var/run/ssl_scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/apps/sstp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"
    ServerName localhost.somedomain.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.key"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log" \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

my tomcat server.xml is as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

    <GlobalNamingResources>
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443"
                    address="127.0.0.1"
                    maxThreads="1500"
                    acceptCount="100"
                    secure="@tomcat.session.secure@"/>
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                  xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
                <Context docBase="/apps/sstp/tomcat/html" path="/info"/>

            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

In very simple words i want to configure whatever is needed to make my application running as `http://localhost.somedomain.com`  to run over ssl as `https://localhost.somedomain.com`

Comment: Is your tomcat actually serving *anything*? All I see from your setup is an apache-HTTP-server serving files from a directory called "/apps/sstp/tomcat/webapps/ROOT". Your question says you want to set up SSL on tomcat, but you do it on the apache? What sort of connection do you use between apache and tomcat - http or ajp? What port(s) is tomcat listening on? Your entire setup is unclear...

Comment: Yes tomcat is serving my web application perfectly - http version. http://localhost.somedomain.com is being perfectly being served. I have added my server.xml entry above  . It seems to Use AJP

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how your apache would pass any request to tomcat, since i can nowhere see the address of the tomcat-ajp-connector (most likely `localhost:8009`, at least the port 8009 should be mentioned somwhere), so I don't understand how it could possibly work over plain http....

Comment: What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You should have all your `SSL` options in the same place: in your `VirtualHost`.

Answer (score 1):

This is missing in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Because of this, request is not routed from apache to tomcat

Comment: This solved the issue. I dont have enough reputation to upvote yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By the description in your question I read that you set up SSL on the apache and want to pass the requests to tomcat using the AJP-protocol. In that case you should not specify the `DocumentRoot` of your `VirtualHost` to be some tomcat-directory but you should instead specify the correct `JkMount` (if you are using mod_jk) or `ProxyPass` (if you are using mod_proxy_ajp) directives. Take a look at the configuration of your virtual host on port 80, it should contain the correct statements and you could just copy them over to your SSL-virtualHost.

Comment: have added more config files. for clarity